# Automatically install extensions in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there some way to automatically install VS Code extensions when opening a project (like package.json but for vscode?)

If not, is there some way to install extensions at the command line?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue that @daniel-imms created was resolved in June 2017. You can see this in the latest version:

```
$ code -h
Visual Studio Code 1.16.0

Usage: code [options] [paths...]

Options:
  --extensions-dir <dir>                                       Set the root path for extensions.
  --list-extensions                                            List the installed extensions.
  --show-versions                                              Show versions of installed extensions, when using --list-extension.
  --install-extension (<extension-id> | <extension-vsix-path>) Installs an extension.
  --uninstall-extension <extension-id>                         Uninstalls an extension.
  --enable-proposed-api <extension-id>                         Enables proposed api features for an extension.
  --disable-extensions                                         Disable all installed extensions.
```

Answer (score 44):

Neither of those are currently possible. I created [an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/691) some time ago for installing extensions via the command line, be sure to give it a +1 to show your interest.

---

### Update

The recommended way of doing this is through [workspace recommended extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions), this is a `.vscode/extensions.json` in your project that will prompt the user to install them when they first open the folder, the file looks like this:

```
{
    "recommendations": [
        "eg2.tslint",
        "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint",
        "msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome"
    ]
}
```

You can also try setting up a bash/bat script or some other automation to directly install the extensions using the CLI as suggested by parsley72 in the other answer. You will likely annoy users by doing this though, unless this is in a personal dotfiles project or something similar.

Comment: Not sure if this is related - any time I open a folder with VSCode for the first time, I get prompted to reinstall extensions I've already added. Is this expected? How can I have these included implicitly?

Comment: @LanceHarper maybe you didn't add some of them? I wouldn't expect that if all the ones in extensions.json are installed.

Answer (score 16):

Thanks to Daniel's suggestion, and I find if you want to keep a list of vscode extensions and install all of them in single click, you can try this approach:

1. Create the list of extensions you want using the [workspace recommended extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_workspace-recommended-extensions)

- Use the `Configure Recommended Extensions` command to create the `extensions.json` file
  [image: Configure Recommended Extensions]
  You will create a file like this:

```
{
  // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=827846 to learn about workspace recommendations.
  // Extension identifier format: ${publisher}.${name}. Example: vscode.csharp
  // List of extensions which should be recommended for users of this workspace.
  "recommendations": [
    "ms-vscode.cpptools",
    "file-icons.file-icons",
    "shd101wyy.markdown-preview-enhanced",
    "sagebind.mathpad",
    "johnpapa.vscode-peacock"
  ],
  // List of extensions recommended by VS Code that should not be recommended for users of this workspace.
  "unwantedRecommendations": []
}
```

- Add your favorite vscode extension id into the list in JSON

2. Re-launch vscode to open the workspace folder (the parent folder for `.vscode` folder)
3. Navigate to "Extensions", filter extensions using "Recommended" filter
   [image: filter extensions]
4. A list of extensions will be shown in "Workspace Recommendations"
5. Click the ☁️ button to install all extensions at once
   [image]

Comment: You can sink your extensions using a Github account as well.

Answer (score 10):

See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_command-line-extension-management

I wrote this `Makefile` to automatically install extensions

```
freeze-extensions:
    code --list-extensions > extensions.txt

install-extensions:
    cat extensions.txt | xargs -L 1 code --install-extension
```

Answer (score 1):

For projects where Node.JS/npm is available, this one-liner(-ish) will install all recommended extensions for the workspace via the command line in a single step:

```bash
npx json5 .vscode/extensions.json | \
npx json-cli-tool --path=recommendations --output=newline | \
xargs -L 1 code --install-extension
```

You could imagine documenting this step in a README's local development setup instructions.

##### Breakdown of the command:

It uses [npx](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/commands/npx), which will install the [json-cli-tool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-cli-tool) and [json5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json5) packages from npm if they're not already installed.

```bash
# Compile the extensions.json file from JSON (with comments) to valid JSON
# That's because VS Code's setting files often contain comments
# If yours doesn't, you can skip this step
npx json5 .vscode/extensions.json | \

# Traverse the JSON and extract all extension names
# on a new line from the "recommendations" array
npx json-cli-tool --path=recommendations --output=newline | \

# Which should output:
# "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"
# "stylelint.vscode-stylelint"

# Pass each line from the command above to VS Code's CLI
# as seen in [@weaming's solution][2]
xargs -L 1 code --install-extension
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a VS Code task using the `.runOptions.runOn == "folderOpen"` option to install them when opening the workspace.

Create (or update) file in `.vscode/tasks.json` with the following.  This example assumes `jq` is installed and the `code` CLI command is available.

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "Install All Recommended Extensions",
      "type": "shell",      
      "command": "jq -r '.recommendations[]' ./.vscode/extensions.json | xargs -L 1 code --install-extension",
      "runOptions": {
        "runOn": "folderOpen"
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "silent"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one-liner to install extensions.json recommendations IF you have jq installed:

```
cat .vscode/extensions.json | jq .recommendations[] | xargs -n 1 code --install-extension
```

or with --force (which will install latest version of each extension if they are already installed):

```
cat .vscode/extensions.json | jq .recommendations[] |xargs -I {} echo "code --install-extension {} --force" | bash
```

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a task that do the right job for you, gathering all the answers of this thread and my own powershell experience:

You need to create a `.vscode/tasks.json` file into your workspace wich contains this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Install All Recommended Extensions",
            "type": "shell",
            "windows": {
                "command": "foreach ($ext in (Get-Content -Raw .vscode/extensions.json | ConvertFrom-Json).recommendations) { Write-Host Installing $ext; code --install-extension $ext; }"
            },
            "linux": {
                "command": "cat .vscode/extensions.json | jq .recommendations[] | xargs -n 1 code . --install-extension"
            },
            "runOptions": {
                "runOn": "folderOpen"
            },
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher" : []
        },
    ]
}
```

This will parse your `.vscode/extensions.json` and will install your extensions for you!

It works on linux and windows. Linux users needs to install `jq` before using it:

```
 sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install jq
```